# Hybris extending Backoffice editing area

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I know how to add a field to the editing area in the hmc, but I'm kind of despair with the backoffice.

[image]

Right now I'm trying to extend the `OAuthClientDetailsModel` and try to edit it over the backoffice. For that I extende it over the `core-items.xml`:

```
<typegroup name="OCC">
    <itemtype code="OAuthClientDetails" autocreate="false" generate="false">
        <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="brands" type="StringList" autocreate="false">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
                <persistence type="property"/>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
</typegroup>
```

Until now everything is fine.

Now to the backoffice. For that I need to edit the `backoffice-config.xml`.
My current code, which is not working correctly looks like this:

```
<context merge-by="type" parent="Item" type="OAuthClientDetails" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea name="">
        <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.category.common" merge-mode="append">
            <editorArea:section name="section.oauthclient.scope" merge-mode="append">
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="brands"/>
            </editorArea:section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```

This created a new tab and section with equal names, which I don't.

I have the following questions:

- is there a easy way to figure out the visible tab and section name?
- how can I add in the first tab, into an existing sextion another list of strings or other fields?
- is there somewhere

Comment: There is no `append` value for `merge-mode`. Default is `merge` and that will do what you are trying to do. Read documentation. https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bb7ed5b8669101487f2a7bc6b015366.html#loio1dbfba0c2eb940fe8f6dad126cd0e04d

Comment: Thank you for that advice, but sadly nothing changed. I have still a second tab with the same name. I also tried to reset the backoffice config with F4.

Comment: What Hybris version are you using?

Comment: 6.7 - next problem what I solved is that duplicating tabs. I had to use `hmc.tab.common`. But now my field is not showing anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In every editor area, there two main onglet : essential and administration.
Essential : it's always showing, even when you switch between onglet.
Administration : is the onglet, where all not categorized attributes goes.

If you don't want to create a new onglet, for your attribute, just use the existing onglet/section :

For your type :
sections : hmc.essential, section.oauthclient.basics, section.oauthclient.scope, section.oauthclient.tokenvalidity,section.oauthclient.disabled .

So, lets add it to section section.oauthclient.scope. you need to keep the same tab "hmc.tab.common".

```
    <context merge-by="type" parent="GenericItem" type="OAuthClientDetails" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea">
        <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.common">
            <editorArea:section name="section.oauthclient.scope" merge-mode="append">
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="brands"/>
            </editorArea:section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```